# Excel VBA: Update a Charts X-Axis Min, Max, & Unit Values via click-button event

Tags: vba, charts, excel-2013

I would **profoundly appreciate** assistance from anyone regarding dynamically updating the X-Axis value of an Excel Bar-Chart via EITHER in-sheet formulae OR via VBA-code.

**I've unsuccessfully tried the following**:

---Created a named-range on the 3 in-sheet cells (Q2, R2, & S2) which will always contain the occassionally updated values for:

X-Axis-Minimum,

X-Axis-Maximum, and

X-Axis-Major-Units.

Then typed the following formula into each of the respective /Format.Axis/Axis.Options dialog-interface data-boxes for all of those 3 variables...:

=MAIN!XMIN

=MAIN!XMAX

=MAIN!XUNITS

[image: /Format.Axis/Axis.Options dialog-interface]

...respectively, where "MAIN" is the name I've assigned to Sheet1.

However, the dialog-interface data-boxes do not retain the formulas, but simply revert back to whatever data was previously in there.

**Alternatively, I've tried to solve this via VBA using the following algorithm variations tied to an ActiveX-Control button named "ReCalibrateButton".**

Please help me determine which of the following algorithm iterations is most efficient and closest to accurate; as well as what's missing or wrong  and preventing it from working successfully:

## (Algorithm #1)

```
Private Sub ReCalibrateButton_Click()
  Dim wsChart As Chart
  Dim wsInput As Worksheet

  Set wsChart = EAMPVPMSChart 
  Set wsInput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN")
  With wsChart
    With .Axes(xlCategory)
        .MinimumScale = wsInput.Range("Q2").Value
        .MaximumScale = wsInput.Range("R2").Value           
        .MajorUnit = wsInput.Range("S2").Value
    End With
  End With
End Sub
```

When run, this algorithm unfortunately yields the following error= **"Compile Error: Variable not defined"**

What have i missed or done wrong within this algorithm?

## (Algorithm #2)

```
Private Sub ReCalibrateButton_Click()
  Dim objCht As ChartObject
  For Each objCht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    With objCht.Chart
      ' Value (X) Axis
      With .Axes(xlCategory)
        .MinimumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("Q2").Value
        .MaximumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("R2").Value
        .MajorUnit = ActiveSheet.Range("S2").Value
      End With
    End With
  Next objCht
End Sub
```

When run, this algorithm unfortunately yields the following
error= **"Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)' Method 'MinimumScale' of object 'Axis' failed"**

What have i missed or done wrong within this algorithm?

## (Algorithm #3)

```
Private Sub ReCalibrateButton_Click()
  Dim wsChart As Chart
  Dim wsInput As Worksheet

  Set wsChart = ThisWorksheet.Charts("EAMPVPMSChart")
  Set wsInput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN")

  With wsChart
    With .Axes(xlCategory)
        .MinimumScale = wsInput.Range("Q2").Value
        .MaximumScale = wsInput.Range("R2").Value           
        .MajorUnit = wsInput.Range("S2").Value
    End With
  End With
End Sub
```

When run, this algorithm unfortunately yields the following
error= **"Compile Error: Variable not defined"**

What have i missed or done wrong within this algorithm?

## (Algorithm #4)

```
Private Sub ReCalibrateButton_Click()
    Dim wksCharts As Worksheet
    Dim oChrtObj As ChartObject

    Set wksCharts = Worksheets("MAIN")
    With wksCharts.ChartObjects("EAMPVPMSChart").Chart
            oChrtObj.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("Q2").Value
            oChrtObj.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("R2").Value
            oChrtObj.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("S2").Value
    End With
End Sub
```

When run, this algorithm unfortunately yields the following
error= **"Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set"**

What have i missed or done wrong within this algorithm?

## (Algorithm #5)

```
Private Sub ReCalibrateButton_Click()
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("EAMPVPMSChart").Activate
    With Application.ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
            .MinimumScale = wsInput.Range("Q2").Value
            .MaximumScale = wsInput.Range("R2").Value
            .MajorUnit = wsInput.Range("S2").Value
    End With
End Sub
```

When run, this algorithm unfortunately yields the following
error= **"Compile Error: Variable not defined"**

What have i missed or done wrong within this algorithm?

Comment: Please [edit] code into the question. Not as images.

Comment: @MihaiChelaru I only used images earlier, because the stackoverflow website interface kept scrambling the formatting and indentations within my pasted code above, and i felt it may not be easily readable for everyone in here. However, now i've figured out how to preserve most of the formatting & indentations, and have edited my original post by adding the plain text for all my VBA algorithms above. Thanks for alerting me to this issue... And besides that, I'd appreciate any assistance you can offer on my 'VBA Charts X-Axis dynamic assignment' question above.

Comment: @QHarr I only used images earlier, because the stackoverflow website interface kept scrambling the formatting and indentations within my pasted code above, and i felt it may not be easily readable for everyone in here. However, now i've figured out how to preserve most of the formatting & indentations, and have edited my original post by adding the plain text for all my VBA algorithms above. Thanks for alerting me to this issue... And besides that, I'd appreciate any assistance you can offer on my 'VBA Charts X-Axis dynamic assignment' question above.

Comment: @Mr_Jack_Storm - Read the simple markup code help. To make an entire block of code look like code, indent the entire block four spaces and paste it into the post.

Comment: Algorithm 1 - it doesn't know what `EAMPVPMSChart` means.

Comment: Algorithm 2 - If the X axis is not a date axis, or if the chart is not a scatter chart, you cannot set axis parameters like min, max, and major unit.

Comment: Algorithm 3 - I don't know what that error means for that code.

Comment: Algorithm 4 - You haven't set `oChrtObj`. If you remove `oChrtObj.Chart` from the items in the With block, it might work, subject to my comment on Algo 2.

Comment: Algorithm 5 - You have not declared nor set `wsInput`.

Comment: You might check my tutorial [Link Excel Chart Axis Scale to Values in Cells](https://peltiertech.com/link-excel-chart-axis-scale-to-values-in-cells/). I would also avoid using ActiveX controls, since they are much flakier than Form controls.

Comment: You might also check out an alternative approach that I think might be easier and more robust, at [Chart Min Max UDF Code](https://exceloffthegrid.com/chart-axis-min-mix/chart-min-max-udf-code/).

Comment: I've elaborated on this alternative approach in [Chart UDF to Control Axis Scale](https://peltiertech.com/chart-udf-control-axis-scale/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void foryou(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet TheWorksheet)
    {
        double MyMajorUnit;
        double MaxSelect = 10;
        double MinSelect = 0;
        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObject TheChartObject in TheWorksheet.ChartObjects())
        {
            TheChartObject.Chart.Axes(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue).MajorUnitIsAuto = false;
            TheChartObject.Chart.Axes(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue).MaximumScaleIsAuto = false;
            TheChartObject.Chart.Axes(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = true;
            TheChartObject.Chart.Axes(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue).MajorGridlines.Format.Line.Visible = true;
            TheChartObject.Chart.Axes(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue).MajorGridlines.Format.Line.Weight = 0.5;
            TheChartObject.Chart.Axes(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue).MajorGridlines.Format.Line.Transparency = 0.5;
            TheChartObject.Chart.Axes(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue).MajorGridlines.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = Color.FromArgb(160, 160, 160);
            MyMajorUnit = (MaxSelect - MinSelect) / 6;
            TheChartObject.Chart.Axes(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue).MajorUnit = MyMajorUnit;
            TheChartObject.Chart.Axes(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue).MaximumScale = MaxSelect + MyMajorUnit;
            TheChartObject.Chart.Axes(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue).MinimumScale = MinSelect - MyMajorUnit;
        }
    }
```

-o-o-o-
Good Luck
Lucien